# mysql sum with if statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sum

I have the following query:

```
SELECT BaDebet2 - BaCredit2 AS TOTAL FROM balansen
```

**edit**

I only want to sum up all BaDebet2 records when TOTAL is greater then 0

Comment: Your question is confusing, even to someone like me that's done a _lot_ of double entry accounting apps. You might want to show some examples where this is useful. Specifically, why would you want to add in the debit values twice? That's not going to balance the books at all. In short, it _is_ possible but it's probably not a good idea :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that will solve your problem. The second query will deliver BaDebet2 if BaDebet2 - BaCredit2>0, otherwise 0.

```
SELECT SUM(BaDebet2_Actual) FROM 
(SELECT IF(BaDebet2 - BaCredit2>0, BaDebet2 ,0) AS BaDebet2_Actual 
 FROM balansen) A;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want, right?

```
SELECT SUM(BaDebet2 - BaCredit2) AS TOTAL, IF(SUM(BaDebet2 - BaCredit2) > 0, SUM(BaDebet2 - BaCredit2) + BaDebet2, NULL) FROM balansen
```

if `TOTAL` > 0 you have `BaDebet2 + TOTAL` in the second column, otherwise you get NULL.

Comment: Yes, that's what i want, but unfortunately i made a miscalculation. I want to make a balance but this was not the right way. Sorry for that but thank you all for helping.

Comment: Note that OP says *For each record from the table ...*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN SUM(BaDebet2 - BaCredit2)>0 
         THEN SUM(BaDebet2 - BaCredit2) + BaDebet2 
    ELSE SUM(BaDebet2 - BaCredit2) END AS TOTAL
FROM balansen
```

Comment: Marco, Thanks for your answer but i need the CASE for each record and not for the SUM. Do you know if that's possible?